# Automatically persisting reverse relationship in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity `User`, that can have exactly one `Company`. I have a `Company`, that can be assigned to multiple `User` objects.

Currently if I want to persist a `User`, I need to get the `Company` (as it may exist without any `User` being assigned to it) and assign it. Further more **I have to add the `User` *manually* to the `Company` using `Company#addUser`**. Afterwards I save run `CompanyRepository.save(company)` (which should suffice to persist the `User`, too, I think, because I am using `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST`).

**Is there a way to say, that if I get the `User` and assign a `Company` to it, the "back-reference" is dealt with automatically?** Or do I always have to get the `Company` and use `Company#addUser` to add that reference?

My entities look like this *(I omitted more properties and reduced it to the most important properties and methods)*:

**Company.java**

```java
package com.portal.user.persistence;
(imports omitted)

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder (toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table (name = "companies")
public class Company {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue (generator = "uuid")
  @GenericGenerator (name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
  @Column (name = "id")
  private String id;

  @Column (name = "ucid")
  private String ucid;

  @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private List<User> users;

  public void addUser(@NonNull User user) {
    if (users == null) {
      users = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    users.add(user);
  }

  public void removeUser(@NonNull User user) {
    users.remove(user);
  }
}
```

**User.java**

```java
package com.portal.user.persistence;
(imports omitted)

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder (toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table (name = "users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue (generator = "uuid")
  @GenericGenerator (name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
  @Column (name = "id")
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Company company;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of answers to your question, based on the implementation you would like to achieve.

- The first way is to remove the @OneToMany relation in Company and the user list. In this way you would only have to manage one side of the relation, and when you need to search for all users in a company you could use a custom query performing a left join on users and companies tables.
- The second way, keeping both side of the relation, is to implement a method 'setCompany' inside the User class like the following:

```java
public void setCompany(Company c){
    c.addUser(this);
    this.company = c;
}
```

However in my experience, the first solution fits better since less relations will lead to a lot less work to do later on, especially regarding DTO conversion and deletion of elements from the DB.

Comment: Thank you! I've went for a version of your second way. I had hoped, that I could **still keep the `Company#users` list while not having to maintain it**. `User#setCompany` with `company = null` should not just dissociate the `User` from a `Company`, but also remove the current `User` instance from the `Company#users` list. Sadly this is not done automatically. When a `User#company` is set to a value, I have to add or remove the back-reference (from `Company#users`) myself. Shouldn't that be necessary, because I specify `mappedBy = "company"` on `Company#users`?